# List all files from sdcard

Tags: android, file-io, sd-card

```
            if (folder.listFiles() != null) {
                for (File file : folder.listFiles()) {
                    if (file.isFile()) {
                        Log.v("vvv", "file with name " + folder.getName() + " in path " + folder.getAbsolutePath());
                    } 
                    }
                }
```

This prints something like this

```
   /vvv     ( 3940): Folder with name .thumbnails in path /sdcard/DCIM/.thumbnails
V/vvv     ( 3940): file with name .thumbnails in path /sdcard/DCIM/.thumbnails
V/vvv     ( 3940): file with name .thumbnails in path /sdcard/DCIM/.thumbnails
V/vvv     ( 3940): file with name .thumbnails in path /sdcard/DCIM/.thumbnails
V/vvv     ( 3940): file with name .thumbnails in path /sdcard/DCIM/.thumbnails
V/vvv     ( 3940): file with name .thumbnails in path /sdcard/DCIM/.thumbnails
V/vvv     ( 3940): file with name .thumbnails in path /sdcard/DCIM/.thumbnails
V/vvv     ( 3940): file with name .thumbnails in path /sdcard/DCIM/.thumbnails
V/vvv     ( 3940): file with name .thumbnails in path /sdcard/DCIM/.thumbnails
V/vvv     ( 3940): Folder with name Camera in path /sdcard/DCIM/Camera
V/vvv     ( 3940): file with name Camera in path /sdcard/DCIM/Camera
V/vvv     ( 3940): file with name Camera in path /sdcard/DCIM/Camera
V/vvv     ( 3940): file with name Camera in path /sdcard/DCIM/Camera
V/vvv     ( 3940): file with name Camera in path /sdcard/DCIM/Camera
V/vvv     ( 3940): file with name Camera in path /sdcard/DCIM/Camera
V/vvv     ( 3940): file with name Camera in path /sdcard/DCIM/Camera
V/vvv     ( 3940): file with name Camera in path /sdcard/DCIM/Camera
V/vvv     ( 3940): file with name Camera in path /sdcard/DCIM/Camera
```

I do some idiotic thing in the code, but I do not know what...

I want to list all the folders and all the files from the sdcard...

can you help me found my bug, Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for (File file : folder.listFiles()) {
    if (file.isFile()) {
       Log.v("vvv", "file with name " + folder.getName() + " in path " + folder.getAbsolutePath());
    } else {
                                        ^^^^^^
```

You probably meant `file.getName()`.